# How to get the youtube favorites url

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, youtube-api

I made the following

```
var NAME = 'youtube';
var SCOPE = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
//var URL = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default";
var URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites?v=2";

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("youtube");
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, googleOAuth_()).getContentText(); 
  var xmlOutput = Xml.parse(data, false);  
  var favorites = xmlOutput.getElement().getElements('entry');  

  app.add(app.createLabel(favorites.length.toString()))
  for(var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++){
  app.add(app.createLabel(favorites[i].getElement('title').getText()))
  //var testf = favorites[i].getElement('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#favorite','href');
}

return app;
}   

function googleOAuth_() {
var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(NAME);
 oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope='+SCOPE);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken');
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken');
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
 return {oAuthServiceName:NAME, oAuthUseToken:'always'};
}
```

To get the title of the favorite videos it works fine 
But I can´t find the way how to get to the url of the favorite video.
where can I find that in the documentation?

And than another question, when I try to execute the script 
with another google account it still gives the error:  
 
*Authorization is required to perform that action*

Isn´t the `googleOAuth_()` funcion taking care of that?

Comment: About your last point: how did you deploy the webapp?Running as you or as user executing the app?

Comment: if you require authorization from the other account it works only from the script editor. see [issue 677](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677)

Comment: *user accessing the web app* and *anyone*  and the page is available for anyone who has the link.

Comment: This can't be true, another long term issue 677??

Comment: Have you tried the new code?

Comment: Noop @Sergeinsas I hadn´t the time to dedicate to GAS these days, I'll let you know when I try. I see the code `getElement('link').getAttribute('href')`  Do you have a link to some documentation where you found it or was it a matter of trial and error.

Comment: I first tried ‘favorites[i].getElement('link').toXmlString()‘ and saw that it had 3 attributes, one of them being 'href' then after simplification and different trials I came up to this code, just added some "decoration" to make it look nicer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution...

(EDIT : better code)

```
var NAME = 'youtube';
var SCOPE = 'http://gdata.youtube.com';
//var URL = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default";
var URL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/favorites?v=2";

function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("youtube").setStyleAttribute('padding','20');
    var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, googleOAuth_()).getContentText(); 
    var xmlOutput = Xml.parse(data, true);  
    var favorites = xmlOutput.getElement().getElements('entry');  
    app.add(app.createLabel('YouTube favourites entries : '+favorites.length.toString()).setStyleAttribute('padding','10'))
    var table = app.createFlexTable().setWidth('400').setStyleAttribute('background', '#ffffdd')

  for(var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++){

      if(favorites[i].getElement('link')){  
      var url = favorites[i].getElement('link').getAttribute('href').getValue();}

      if(favorites[i].getElement('title')){
       var Title = favorites[i].getElement('title').getText()}

      table.setText(i, 0, 'Clip Title : '+Title).setWidget(i, 1, app.createAnchor('link', url)).setBorderWidth(1)  
    }
    app.add(table)
 return app;
}
```