# Filtering out just the link to a YouTube video from an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts to get the body of an email. I am trying to have it only save the link that is contained inside a normal YouTube email, which notifies you of an upload from a new user. I would like to, using JavaScript only save the link that is followed when clicking on the image contained in the email. Seen below is a sample of how part of the email looks:

[image: email sample]

The content of the email is this:

```
    <div>
<table width="620" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center"><tr><td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
<table width="578" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td height="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top">
<img src="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/email/digest/email_header.png">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<div style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#cccccc">
<table width="578" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td height="22" colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>
<td width="498">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="left" width="50">
<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/i/N5jZlcpSP00e_zShDw9EfQ/1.jpg" height="50" width="50">
</td>
<td width="16"></td>
<td>
<div style="font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#333333;line-height:24px" height="59">
FatalDubstepHD has uploaded <b>Empressto - No Love [Dubstep]</b>.
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td height="22"></td></tr>
</table>
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1"></div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td height="22"></td></tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:480px;margin:0 9px">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTYri0ei45Q&amp;feature=em-uploademail" style="text-decoration:none;display:block" class="nonplayable" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/zTYri0ei45Q/hqdefault.jpg" height="360" width="480" border="0">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="480">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTYri0ei45Q&amp;feature=em-uploademail" style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank">
<div style="font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;color:#333333;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold">
Empressto - No Love [Dubstep]
</div>
</a>
<div style="font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#999999;line-height:20px">
by
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/FatalDubstepHD?feature=em-uploademail" style="font-size:13px;color:#999999;line-height:20px;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">FatalDubstepHD</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td height="16"></td></tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="498">
<div style="font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#333333;line-height:20px">
● Free Download<br><a href="https://soundcloud.com/empresstoro/empressto-no-love" target="_blank">https://soundcloud.com/<WBR>empresstoro/empressto-no-love</a><br><br>● Empressto <br><a href="http://www.facebook.com/EmpreSSto" target="_blank">http://www.facebook.com/<WBR>EmpreSSto</a><br><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Empressto" target="_blank">http://www.twitter.com/<WBR>Empressto</a><br><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOfficialEmpressto" target="_blank">http://www.youtube.com/user/<WBR>TheOfficialEmpressto</a><br><br>● Fatal Dubstep<br><a href="http://www.facebook.com/FatalMusicUK" target="_blank">http://www.facebook.com/<WBR>FatalMusicUK</a><br><a href="http://www.twitter.com/FatalMusicUK" target="_blank">http://www.twitter.com/<WBR>FatalMusicUK</a><br><br>● Owner Of Fatal<br><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Mihalis_Costa" target="_blank">http://www.twitter.com/<WBR>Mihalis_Costa</a><br><br>● Contact Email/Submit Music<br><a href="mailto:fatalmusicsubmission@gmail.com" target="_blank">fatalmusicsubmission@gmail.com</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="40"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="22" colspan="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>
<td width="498">
<div style="color:#999999;line-height:14px;font-size:11px;font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif">
You were sent this email because you chose to receive updates about new videos uploaded by <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/FatalDubstepHD?feature=em-uploademail" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1c62b9" target="_blank">FatalDubstepHD</a>. If you don&#39;t want these updates anymore, you can change your preferences by visiting the <a href="http://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager" style="text-decoration:none;color:#1c62b9" target="_blank">subscription manager</a>.
</div>
</td>
<td width="40"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="40"></td>
<td width="498">
<div style="color:#999999;font-size:11px;line-height:14px;font-family:arial,Arial,sans-serif">
©2013 YouTube, LLC 901 Cherry Ave, San Bruno, CA 94066
</div>
</td>
<td width="40"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="22"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

The problem here is, how do I filter out just the url from an email like this, and also it looks like the text `3D` is being added to the url, which is making the url invalid, so I'd also need to remove that from the url. Any ideas of how I could do this?

EDIT:

Here is the code I am using, which is missing the parse data:

```
function processInbox() {
  // get all threads in inbox
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social/YouTube/Dubstep");
  var doneLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social/YouTube/Dubstep (added)");
  var messages = label.getThreads();
  var max = Math.min(messages.length,1);
  for( var i = 0; i < max; ++i ) {
    var email = messages[i].getMessages()[0];
    var contents = email.getBody();

    //PARSE HERE
    var xml = Xml.parse(contents,true);
    Logger.log(xml);
    GmailApp.sendEmail('MY EMAIL', 'Xml Contents', Logger.getLog());



    //messages[i].markRead();
    //messages[i].removeLabel(label).addLabel(doneLabel);
  }
};
```

EDIT2: New Code:

```
function processInbox() {
  // get all threads in inbox
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social/YouTube/Dubstep");
  var doneLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Social/YouTube/Dubstep (added)");
  var messages = label.getThreads();
  var max = Math.min(messages.length,5);
  for( var i = 0; i < max; ++i ) {
    var email = messages[i].getMessages()[0];
    var contents = email.getBody();
    var st = contents.indexOf('<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
    var str1 = contents.substr(st+9,80);
    var end = str1.indexOf('&amp');
    var link = str1.substring(0,end);
    Logger.log(link); 
    GmailApp.sendEmail('EMAIL', 'Xml Contents', Logger.getLog());

    Logger.clear();

    //messages[i].markRead();
    //messages[i].removeLabel(label).addLabel(doneLabel);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best approach would be to use the `XML service` to parse the HTML and from there get the elements.

See [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_xml?hl=fr-FR#parse), set the lenient parameter to `true`

I used a similar approach [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185320/how-to-get-the-youtube-favorites-url/14198009#14198009) some time ago, you can see the idea...

---

**EDIT :**
i didn't succeeded with this approach...
I tried something else using string operations :

```
...
var contents = email.getBody();
var st = contents.indexOf('<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
var str1 = contents.substr(st+9,80);
var end = str1.indexOf('&amp');
var link = str1.substring(0,end);
Logger.log(link);
```

it works for this case, you will have to check if it works all the time.

Note : I tested on other shared links sent by email from youTube and it seemed to work every time ;-)

Comment: This method is not really using the functions in Google Scripts then is it? I have updated the main post with the exact output of one of the emails using getBody(). Is there actually anyway to getXML data using the built in functions of Google Scripts?

Comment: ?? XML service is a defauld service in Google script... I don't really understand your comment. sorry if I missed something.

Comment: I added the code I am currently looking to use. Is there any way to use code like I have now, or must I totally change it to use your XML method? If I must change it, in what way would I do that? I'm pretty new to Javascript and Google Scripts, so I was looking for a basic solution, but I guess it is not going to be one?

Comment: it is not too hard to play with... I don't have similar email to test on my side but `XML.parse` will return `elements` you can `log` to see how it is built and then get the `href` you are looking for... the example in the other post shows how to do it.

Comment: I updated my code in the main post showing the code I tried. The content I was emailed was just the same as the content part before. It is not formatted like xml at all. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Would you like to send me an email with your example's content so I can test how to parse it?  I logged in your wp site so you have my mail adres

Comment: I've sent you an email but the XML still looks just like the HTML. I'm using the code in my original post. Did I do something wrong in it? Also I emailed you.

Comment: Okay, that code works! It is returning a URL, but using the updated code in my post, I am receiving 5 emails, each with multiple links. Some links were from the previous email, some are not. It should be returning 1 link per email, do you know what reason it would not be doing so?

Comment: Are you talking about messages or threads ? since you used `var messages = Label.getThreads()` in your code there might be a confusion there... do you want to get the url in each message or in each thread ?

Comment: What exactly is a thread? I basically have a bunch of videos being labled that are from YouTube music channels. I am just trying to have this script be run twice a day checking for new emails in this label. If there is a new email in the label, it takes the video url and adds it to the spreadsheet I have. This functionality I have done. I guess I am getting confused on the difference between a thread and message? Is there something I need to modify?

Comment: A thread in gmail is a serie of messages with the same subject and between the same email adress, it can contain many messages, typically message+reply+re-reply...it can be grouped in the gmail web interface when you activate the conversation mode (not sure it is called like this because I'm in a french interface but I think so) and in most mail client programs like thunderbird or Apple mail. In your case I don't know how these messages from youtube are coming and how they are identified but maybe they are grouped in threads if they have the same subject...

Comment: It looks like this http://i.imgur.com/FVioOuS.png . I don't believe they are threaded, so each thread should be one message. Using a 3 message limit on the for loop, I receive the correct amount of emails (3), though I end up getting messages like this : http://i.imgur.com/kyqaCFn.png . The messages should only contain 1 link if I am correct?